# Pandas pd.to_datetime causing corrupted date values in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is a weird error I'm getting with Pandas and I can't account for it.  I am reading a CSV file into a dataframe and some how it is getting duplicate index values for the time column they have no correspondence in the CSV file.  By adding in debugging I think I have narrowed the issue down to these three lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df[time_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[time_col].astype(str).values, format='%Y.%m')
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
df.set_index(time_col, inplace=True)
```

time_col has the value "TIME_REF" verified by the debugger.

From the debugger I examined the contents of the data frame

```
(scipy) (xxx) stats $ python  stats.py --csv Rental-price-indexes-April-2021.csv --series CPIM.SE9041F --plot rental.png
> /home/xxx/projects/stats/stats.py(61)<module>()
-> df.set_index(time_col, inplace=True)
(Pdb) 
(Pdb) df[df['SER_REF'] =='CPIM.SE9041F']
           SER_REF   TIME_REF  DATA_VAL STATUS  ... Series_title_1              Series_title_2 Series_title_3 Unnamed: 10
870   CPIM.SE9041F 2006-11-01      1000  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
871   CPIM.SE9041F 2006-12-01       992  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
872   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-01-01      1025  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
873   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-02-01      1028  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
874   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-03-01      1022  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
...            ...        ...       ...    ...  ...            ...                         ...            ...         ...
1039  CPIM.SE9041F 2020-12-01      1547  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1040  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-01-01      1563  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1041  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-02-01      1567  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1042  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-03-01      1563  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1043  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-04-01      1560  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN

[174 rows x 11 columns]
(Pdb) df[df['SER_REF'] =='CPIM.SE9041F'].sort_values('TIME_REF')
           SER_REF   TIME_REF  DATA_VAL STATUS  ... Series_title_1              Series_title_2 Series_title_3 Unnamed: 10
870   CPIM.SE9041F 2006-11-01      1000  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
871   CPIM.SE9041F 2006-12-01       992  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
872   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-01-01      1025  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
881   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-01-01      1055  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
873   CPIM.SE9041F 2007-02-01      1028  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
...            ...        ...       ...    ...  ...            ...                         ...            ...         ...
1039  CPIM.SE9041F 2020-12-01      1547  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1040  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-01-01      1563  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1041  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-02-01      1567  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1042  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-03-01      1563  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
1043  CPIM.SE9041F 2021-04-01      1560  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN

[174 rows x 11 columns]
(Pdb)
```

The original data file (showing only those lines for 2007 and for that data series) contains:

```
(xxx) stats $ cat Rental-price-indexes-April-2021.csv | grep CPIM.SE9041F | grep 2007
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.01,1025,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.02,1028,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.03,1022,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.04,1024,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.05,1034,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.06,1028,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.07,1039,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.08,1046,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.09,1049,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.10,1055,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.11,1062,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
CPIM.SE9041F,2007.12,1058,FINAL,Index,CPI,CPI Monthly Rents (National),National,Actual rentals for housing,Flow,
(xxx) stats $
```

Yet I am getting duplicate entries for 2007-01-01 which you can see from the sorted data frame.
I believe I am using Pandas 1.0.3.   I also tried upgrading to Pandas 1.1.5 but am getting the same result.

I tried one more thing which I think might have narrowed the problem down a bit.  I looked at the data series prior to converting the date column and then tried creating a new column "time" with pd.to_datetime and the compared the entries. It really does appear to be an issue with the 'format="%Y.%m" ' option inconsistently doing the date conversion even though the documentation for strptime indicates that %m should take into account leading zeros.

```
(Pdb) df2 = df[df['SER_REF'] =='CPIM.SE9041F'].copy()
(Pdb) df2.head()
          SER_REF  TIME_REF  DATA_VAL STATUS  ... Series_title_1              Series_title_2 Series_title_3 Unnamed: 10
870  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.11      1000  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
871  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.12       992  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
872  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.01      1025  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
873  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.02      1028  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN
874  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.03      1022  FINAL  ...       National  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN

[5 rows x 11 columns]
(Pdb) df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2[time_col].astype(str).values, format='%Y.%m')
(Pdb) df2.head()
          SER_REF  TIME_REF  DATA_VAL STATUS  ...              Series_title_2 Series_title_3 Unnamed: 10       time
870  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.11      1000  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2006-11-01
871  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.12       992  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2006-12-01
872  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.01      1025  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-01-01
873  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.02      1028  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-02-01
874  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.03      1022  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-03-01

[5 rows x 12 columns]
(Pdb) df2.sort_values('time').head()
          SER_REF  TIME_REF  DATA_VAL STATUS  ...              Series_title_2 Series_title_3 Unnamed: 10       time
870  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.11      1000  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2006-11-01
871  CPIM.SE9041F   2006.12       992  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2006-12-01
872  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.01      1025  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-01-01
881  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.10      1055  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-01-01
873  CPIM.SE9041F   2007.02      1028  FINAL  ...  Actual rentals for housing           Flow         NaN 2007-02-01

[5 rows x 12 columns]
(Pdb)
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this with Pandas?  At least now I have a work around if I find out this is beyond the ability of Pandas and that this is something that Pandas can't do but that would surprise me as I tried the same thing with just python strptime and it does it correctly.

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal reproducible example? using `s = pd.Series(['2006.11', '2006.12', '2007.01', '2007.10', '2007.02', '2007.03'])` and `pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str).values, format='%Y.%m')` gives the right results

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I thought maybe covid had killed off stackoverflow.  I have kind of figured it out.  It was nothing to do with pd.to_datetime and everything to do with pd.read_csv which was interpreting my raw data date column as floating point numbers and truncating the trailing zero based on what is was inferring, wrongly, about my data set.  That means, with that information coming to light, my question turns out to be wrongly titled which was impossible for me to know beforehand.  The better question would be how to turn off this behaviour with pd.read_csv

Comment: you could either specify `dtype=object` for the entire dataframe or  specify the dtype of the column that you're trying to read in as a date or use the `parse_dates` parameter in `pd.read_csv`